# Cannot change background-color of twitter bootstrap odd table's rows

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-color

I've a table stiled with Twitter Bootstrap css files.
The table is defined like follow:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
...
</table>
```

with jQuery I add a class called ".red-background" after the click event on a button in the table's row.

```
.red-background
{
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

The problem is that the code works fine on the pair rows, but not in the odd!
I don't know why, but removing the table's classes "table-striped" and "table-hover", all works fine.
The "color" rule defined in the "red-background" class, ever works, but the "background-color" on odd rows no.

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: add a jsfiddle and we can help you

Comment: I cannot share Jsfiddle, because I've a lot on local css files linked!

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS class

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Hope that will work.

Comment: This adds a static color to the odd rows.

Comment: I want to do this via jQuery with .addClass method

Comment: please add a jsfiddle so taht I can help you

Comment: I cannot share Jsfiddle, because I've a lot on local css files linked!!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043759/overriding-bootstrap-table-striped-css):

Add a class to your CSS that specifically overrides the rule from striping and add it under your other CSS rule. For your example, this is the markup.

```
table.table.table-striped tr.red-background td {
    background-color: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```