# Overriding bootstrap table-striped CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background-color of rows that contain my `found` class in a striped bootstrap table. It works for even rows because bootstrap doesn't have a background color for them, but odd rows I am blocked by bootstraps CSS.

**Bootstrap CSS:**

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

**Custom CSS:**

```
 tr.found{
    background-color:#CECBCB;
}
```

How would I override bootstrap's CSS for only a single row at a time (as you can see in demo, odd rows are not overridden)?

[BOOTPLY DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/X03H5roc3D)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Write specific selector to override the bootstrap ones

```
table.table.table-striped tr.found td {
    background-color:#CECBCB;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/NPCMvSlQvj)

Also, not only specificity matters here, make sure you apply the background to the `td` element and not the `tr` because bootstrap is applying to the `td` element so even if you apply the background to `tr` won't make sense.

---

As you said that you wanted the explanation for the selector I wrote, so here it goes, let us break that and understand..

Starting off with this

`table.table.table-striped` - Over here am selecting a `table` element having classes `.table` AS WELL AS `.table-striped`

Going further with the selector, `tr.found` we select the `tr` elements having a `class` called `.found` and lastly, we select the nested `td` elements.

Comment: Could you give me an explanation to following the CSS levels (table.table.table-striped tr.found td)

Comment: @JordanD sure, I'll explain, give me minute

Answer (score 5):

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
tr.found{
    background-color:#CECBCB;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer better, it directly replicates the striped pattern without having to add extra classes

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 5 you can do:

**custom.scss**

```
// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)
$table-striped-bg: rgb(213, 215, 127);

// Include all of bootstrap
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Compile the scss.

That´s it.

Check more table related variables [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#sass-variables).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mr. Alien's solution, I found that the following works in Bootstrap 4 without explicitly overriding the table style.

```
 tr.found td{
    background-color:#CECBCB;
}
```

[Bootply Demo](https://www.bootply.com/pOnx9JdbIN)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap v5.3+; you'll want to override the Bootstrap CSS variable for background-color as well.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr > td.myclass{
    background: blue;
    --bs-table-bg-type: blue;
}
```